# Representing functions $f=\sum^{\infty} a_{i} 1_{A_{i}}$ if f can equal infinity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider measurable functions $f:(S,\mathcal{A},\mu)\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+},\mathcal{B})$, where S is a measure space and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+}=[0,\infty]$. The question is then to show that f can be represented as $f=\sum^{\infty} a_{i} 1_{A_{i}}$ for $a_{i}\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $A_{i}\in \mathcal{A}$.

**Attempt**

Not sure why that is true(if it is).  If f only took discrete values then indeed $f=\sum c_{i}1_{f=c_{i}}$; but maybe $S=\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $f(x)=x$.

Another known way is to use dyadic step functions i.e. $f=lim_{n}\sum^{4^{n}}
\frac{j}{2^{n}}1_{f\geq \frac{j}{2^{n}}}$. But the summand is zero so we can't write $\sum^{\infty}$.

Any suggestions?

This shows up in proving uniqueness of the integral satisfying two axioms: $\int 1_{A}d\mu=\mu(A)$ and $\int \sum c_{i} f_{i}d\mu=\sum c_{i} \int f_{i}d\mu$.

**Attempt at rigorous counterexample**

Let $f:(\mathbb{R}^{+},\mathcal{\Lambda},\lambda)\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+},\mathcal{B})$, where $\Lambda$ are the Lebesgue measurable sets, be defined as $f(x)=x$.

If $f(x)=\sum_{i}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}$ for $a_{i}\geq 0$, then we first rewrite it as $\sum_{i}b_{i}1_{B_{i}}$ where $B_{i}$ are disjoint. Then we have a bijection from $[0,1]$ to a countable subset, which is a countradiction.

Comment: This suggests that $f$ can take at most a countably infinite number of values, which is not the case, for example, for $f(x)=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  I think you are talking about using _limits_ of simple functions to say things about more general functions.

Comment: what is a rigorous way to disprove this claim?

Comment: Actually, it is true http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864903/a-measurable-function-equal-to-a-countable-sum-of-characteristic-functions?rq=1

Comment: Aha, the sets are not necessarily disjoint, I read the problem too quickly and assumed it was one about approximations with simple functions.  Though I would not have expected the answer to be true anyway.

Comment: The explanation in your link is good.

Comment: For the rigorous way if the sets are disjoint: If the sets were disjoint then only one term of the sum could be active at any time, so the set of all possible values $f$ could take would be at most countably infinite.  So any example (like $f(x)=x$) for which $f$ can be one of an uncountably infinite number of possibilities would be a counter-example.  The same would hold for sums where at most a finite number of terms can be active at any one time. Anyway +1 for your comment and question.

Answer (score 0):

Any $x\in \overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+}$ can be represented by it's decimal expansion i.e. $x=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{d_{k}}{10^{k}}$, where $d_{k}=0,...,9$. If $x=\infty$, then $\infty=\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}10^{k}$. Otherwise, there exists N s.t. $x\in (d_{1}10^{N-1},(d_{1}+1)10^{N-1})$ for $d_{1}=0,...,9$. Thus $x-d_{1}10^{N-1}\leq 10^{N-1}$. Repeating this n times we get $x-\sum^{n}d_{k}10^{N-k}\leq 10^{N-n}$ so as $n\to \infty$ we get $x=\sum_{k\geq 1} d_{k}10^{N-k}$.

Thus, let $\{a_{k}\}=\{d_{k}10^{k}+d_{-k}10^{-k}: d_{k}=0,...,9\}$.

Let $A_{k}=\{x\in \overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+}: a_{k}$ in decimal representation of x$\}$ and so $x=\sum a_{k}1_{A_{k}}(x)$ from (i). Therefore, $f(x)=\sum a_{k}1_{f^{-1}( A_{k})}(x)$. The $A_{k}$ are Borel measurable because they are two intervals each containing numbers with fixed digit expansions, the kth and -kth, and so by measurability of f, we have $f^{-1}(A_{k})\in \mathcal{A}$.