# Proof of Dominated convergence without using positive and negative parts

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider measurable functions $f_{n}:(S,\mathcal{A},\mu)\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+},\mathcal{B})$, where S is a measure space and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^{+}=[0,\infty]$. For such functions define the integral as $\int fd\mu:=sup \sum a_{i}\mu(A_{i})$ over all simple functions s.t. $ f\geq \sum a_{i}1_{A_{i}}$.

For $f_{n}\leq g$ with $\int g<\infty$ and $f_{n}\to f$ a.e., DCT says $\lim_{n}\int f_{n} =\int f$.

So one proof involves applying Fatous to $g-f_{n}$, but that requires $\int -f_{n}d\mu=-\int f_{n} d\mu$ and $\int -f_{n}d\mu$ is not defined. Therefore, one has to define $\int f=\int f^{+}d\mu-\int f^{-}d\mu$ for general f.

However, I am wondering if there is a proof of DCT using only the original definition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This a potential answer. This relies on an unproven claim:

$\sum^{\infty}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}\geq \sum^{\infty}b_{i}1_{B_{i}}$, where $a_{i},b_{i}\geq 0$ and the sets possibly intersect i.e. $A_{i}\cap A_{j}\neq \varnothing $ and same with $B_{i}$ then there exist $C_{i}$ and $c_{i}\geq 0$ s.t.
$\sum^{\infty}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}-\sum^{\infty}b_{i}1_{B_{i}}=\sum^{\infty}c_{i}1_{C_{i}}$.

[Is it always true that $\sum^{\infty}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}-\sum^{\infty}b_{i}1_{B_{i}}=\sum^{\infty}c_{i}1_{C_{i}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456574/is-it-always-true-that-sum-inftya-i1-a-i-sum-inftyb-i1-b-i)

Then the same proof of DCT follows up until the step

$\int g-fd\mu\leq \lim_{n}\int g-f_{n}d\mu$.

Then we express $g=\sum g_{i}1_{G_{i}}$, $f=\sum c_{i}1_{C_{i}}$ and $f_{n}=\sum a_{in}1_{A_{in}}$, which we can do as I showed at [Representing functions $f=\sum^{\infty} a_{i} 1_{A_{i}}$ if f can equal infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453898/representing-functions-f-sum-infty-a-i-1-a-i-if-f-can-equal-infinity)

Then using the above claim $\int g-fd\mu=\sum d_{i}\mu(D_{i})=\sum g_{i}\mu(G_{i})-\sum c_{i}\mu(C_{i})=\int gd\mu-\int fd\mu$

and similarly for the RHS of the inequality and so the $\int g d\mu$ cancel out ($\infty-\infty$ does not happen due to finiteness of $\int g$).