# A measurable function is an infinite sum of simple measurable functions. Why measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $\left(E,\mathcal{E}\right)$ a measurable space and let $f:E\to[0,+\infty]$
a measurable function. Then 
$$
f=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}a_{i}\chi_{A_{i}}
$$
with $a_{i}\geq0$ and $A_{i}$ measurable.

In an attempt to solve this problem, I stumbled upon the suggestion of Adam Hughes proposed here:

[A measurable function equal to a countable sum of characteristic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864903/a-measurable-function-equal-to-a-countable-sum-of-characteristic-functions)

The solution is convincing, but **I don't understand how to prove that $A_{i}$
are measurable.**

Briefly recapitulate for those who have not read the other post.

For all $y\in\mathbb{R_+}$ we can find a set $S_{y}\subset\mathbb{N}^{*}$
such that
$$
y=\sum_{k\in S_{y}}\frac{1}{k}
$$

Now we define 
$$
\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\quad\quad A_{k}=\left\{ x\in E\mid k\in S_{f\left(x\right)}\right\} 
$$
Then

$$ \displaystyle
f=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N^*} \frac{1}{k} \chi_{A_{k}}
$$

Answer (score 5):

In case you're interested in another approach: It is standard that there exist simple functions $0=s_0\le s_1\le s_2 \le \cdots$ such that $s_n\to f$ pointwise everywhere. Thus

$$f= (s_1-s_0) +(s_2-s_1) + (s_3-s_2)+ \cdots$$

everywhere. Now each $s_{n}-s_{n-1}$ is itself a simple function, and each is nonnegative. Thus for each $n$ we can write

$$s_{n+1}-s_n = \sum_{j=1}^{k_n}c_{jn}\mathbb 1_{E_{jn}},$$

where all $c_{jn}\ge 0$ and all $E_{jn}$ are measurable. Thus

$$f= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{k_n}c_{jn}\mathbb 1_{E_{jn}}.$$

Since the summands in this double sum are nonnegative, we can linearly order them to form a standard infinite series. The resultant series has the desired form.

Comment: Well, indeed your considerations interest me. But I have to ask you a couple of clarifications.

Comment: Your reasoning leads to considering a series of the type $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k(n)} x^n_j$$
Now, we should define a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k(n)} x^n_j 
=
\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}a_i
 $$

Question: in this case the thing can be done because every time we have a double series we can rewrite it in terms of a single series and, with this new rewriting, are the sums equal?

Comment: I mean, basically what's underneath is that if  I have a double series of the type $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} x^n_k$ then this is the same as the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} y_n$ assuming that 
$$ y_1=x^1_1$$

$$y_2=x^2_1+x^2_2+x^1_2$$  
$$ y_3=x^3_1+x^3_2+x^3_3+x^2_3+x^1_3$$, etc. ?

Comment: Why are you mentioning power series? The basic result here is that if you have a double series $\sum_m \sum_n a_{mn} $ whose terms are nonnegative, then any linear ordering of the $a_{mn}$ into a single series will sum to the same value as the double series.

Comment: is there a missing term ($s_0$) in your sum? shouldn't it be: $f = s_0 + (_1−_0)+(_2−_1) + \dots$ ?