# Is the canonical form of a measurable function measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions, borel-measures, measurable-sets

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space, and let a positive function $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as

\begin{align}
f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\mathbb{I}_{A_n}
\end{align}

with $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathcal{E}$. Is it $\mathcal{E}$-measurable?

**My attempt**
Probably the statement can be proved differently, but in my book (by Cinlar) this exercise follows right after another one that asks to prove the same result **when the $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are disjointed**. So I think it would be nice to express $f$ in canonical form and then leverage on the result from the previous exercise. Since $f$ takes on at most countably many distinct values $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$, it is straightforward to define

\begin{align}
B_m=\{ x \in E : f(x)=b_m \}, \quad m \geq 1
\end{align}

so that

\begin{align}
f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\mathbb{I}_{A_n}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}b_m\mathbb{I}_{B_m}
\end{align}

Now, once I prove that $(B_m)_{m=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{E}$, I can claim that $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable because it is constant on each member of a measurable partition of $E$ (I guess this holds even if $(B_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is not a partition of $E$ as it can be enriched with $B_0=E\setminus (\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}B_m)$).

The point is: how to prove that $B_m$ is an $\mathcal{E}$-measurable set for each $m \geq 1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202102/a-measurable-function-is-an-infinite-sum-of-simple-measurable-functions-why-mea?rq=1

Comment: @FShrike thanks but I don't see an answer to my question in that post. I am assuming that the (not necessariliy disjointed) $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{E}$ and I am wondering if the disjointed $(B_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ that appear in the canonical form are measurable too.