# Decompose measurable function into characteristic functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f : X → [0,∞]$ be measurable. Show that there exist measurable sets $A_k, k = 1,2,...$ such that
$$f =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \chi_{A_k}$$

Where $\chi_{A_k}(x) = 1$ if $x \in A_k$ and $0$ otherwise.

How do I even start to proceed with this problem? I'd be glad if anyone could point me to a relevant resource or gives a general direction for it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864903/a-measurable-function-equal-to-a-countable-sum-of-characteristic-functions?rq=1